# Android : Volley 1.0.18 how to disable request cache?

Tags: android, rest, caching, android-volley

I'm using volley library:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
```

In http helper class i have the following method.

```
  public static JsonRequest createRequest(String responseType, int requestMethod, String scheme,
                                            String url, final String requestParams, final HttpResponseListener listener,
                                            Request.Priority priority) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // Start to prepare request URL
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme(scheme).encodedAuthority(url);
        // GET REQUESTS - append the params into URL
        if (requestMethod == Request.Method.GET && requestParams != null) {
            boolean append = appendParamsToUrl(requestParams, builder);
            if(!append) return null;
        }
        url = URLDecoder.decode(builder.build().toString(), Constants.Request.DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        // Get response as JSON object
        JsonRequest request;
        if (responseType.equals(Constants.Request.JSON_OBJECT)) {
            // Prepare request and set the Callbacks
            request = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(requestMethod, url, requestParams,
                    priority, responseListener(listener), errorListener(listener), listener);
        }else { // Get response as JSON array of objects
            // Prepare request and set the Callbacks
            request = new CustomJsonArrayRequest(requestMethod, url, requestParams,
                    priority, responseArrayListener(listener), errorListener(listener), listener);
        }
        request.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);
        request.setShouldCache(false);
        return request;
    }
```

When i using the option:

```
request.setShouldCache(false);
```

To force disabling cache.

But when i get the response from server from the POSTMAN (Chrome extension for API testing) i got different values in response than on the Android device.

I tried also use the:

```
queue.getCache().clear();
```

But with the same results.

How can i force disable the cache from response?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you mean that Postman got new updated response for each request, but your Android app always got the same (cached) response for all requests?

Comment: Yes, mostly, Android app got different result that postman.

Comment: Pls set breakpoint at `if (request.shouldCache() && response.cacheEntry != null) {` inside `NetworkDispatcher` class, and debug to see if shouldCache is true or false

Comment: Or at the `if (!request.shouldCache()) {` line inside `RequestQueue` class

Comment: mShouldCache = false

Comment: Ok, post the responses you got (both by Postman and Android)

Comment: Do you mean response headers?

Comment: No, the response data

Answer (score 2):

```
request.setShouldCache(false);
```

does not seem to be enough for GET requests.
however, clearing the cache before adding to the queue seems to help

```
myRequestQueue.getCache().clear();
```

I put this in my `getRequestQueue()` method in my Volley singleton before returning `requestQueue`.

Answer (score 2):

Call the following:

```
myRequestQueue.getCache().remove(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

To use Volley without response caching, instead of using Volley.newRequestQueue(), you can create your own RequestQueue as follows:

```
   HttpStack stack;
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        stack = new HurlStack();
   } else {
        stack = new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
   }

   Network network = new BasicNetwork(stack);
   queue = new RequestQueue(new NoCache(), network);
```

The key is the NoCache object which implements the Volley Cache interface but does nothing.

**Bonus:** If you want, you can also implement the HttpStack using OkHttp (shipped with the app). The good thing about that approach is that since you ship the OkHttp library with your app, you can rest assured that your HttpStack implementation will always work on all Android versions since you're not dependent on the platform's HttpStack implementation. Plus OkHttp has all sorts of goodies like the interceptor mechanism and a very simple API.